# Need to transpose specific amount of rows of data with new columns in R

Tags: r, transpose

I am very new to R but need to use it occasionally for my job. I have a .csv file that I need data from the first 14 rows (March through Sept) from only column 6 (Header is SNWD) to transpose horizontally with 14 new column names. I know how to read in the .csv file, just need help with the actual transpose code.

Current .csv format:

```
STN,NAME,MO,DAY,YEAR,SNWD
1234,STATION A,3,1,1919,2
1234,STATION A,3,15,1919,3
1234,STATION A,4,1,1919,1
1234,STATION A,4,15,1919,0
1234,STATION A,5,1,1919,6
1234,STATION A,5,15,1919,0
1234,STATION A,6,1,1919,4
1234,STATION A,6,15,1919,0.5
```

Need the output to look like:

```
March-1,March-15,April-1,April-15,May-1,May-15,June-1,June-15,July-1,July-15,Aug-1,Aug-15    
2,3,1,0,6,0,4,0.5, , , , , ,
```

Would appreciate any help.
Thanks -K-

Comment: Have you tried the function `t()`?

Comment: @Jan, an unstated portion of the question appears to be how to get a formatted date from the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)    
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
dat %>% 
   unite(DATE, YEAR, MO, DAY, sep="-") %>%
   mutate(DATE = format(ymd(DATE), "%b-%d"), rn = rowid(STN, NAME, DATE)) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = DATE, values_from = SNWD)
# A tibble: 1 x 11
#    STN NAME         rn `Mar-01` `Mar-15` `Apr-01` `Apr-15` `May-01` `May-15` `Jun-01` `Jun-15`
# <int> <chr>     <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1  1234 STATION A     1        2        3        1        0        6        0        4      0.5
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(STN = c(1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 
1234L, 1234L), NAME = c("STATION A", "STATION A", "STATION A", 
"STATION A", "STATION A", "STATION A", "STATION A", "STATION A"
), MO = c(3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L), DAY = c(1L, 15L, 1L, 
15L, 1L, 15L, 1L, 15L), YEAR = c(1919L, 1919L, 1919L, 1919L, 
1919L, 1919L, 1919L, 1919L), SNWD = c(2, 3, 1, 0, 6, 0, 4, 0.5
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help akrun!

Comment: Hi akrun, I'm receiving an error:
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `DATE`.
x could not find function "ymd"
i Input `DATE` is `format(ymd(DATE), "%b-%d")`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: @Kris sorry, forgot to add `lubridate`.  Updated

Answer (score 0):

```r
dat <- read.csv(stringsAsFactors=F, text="
STN,NAME,MO,DAY,YEAR,SNWD
1234,STATION A,3,1,1919,2
1234,STATION A,3,15,1919,3
1234,STATION A,4,1,1919,1
1234,STATION A,4,15,1919,0
1234,STATION A,5,1,1919,6
1234,STATION A,5,15,1919,0
1234,STATION A,6,1,1919,4
1234,STATION A,6,15,1919,0.5")

with(dat, setNames(SNWD, format(as.Date(paste(YEAR, MO, DAY, sep="-")), format = "%B-%d")))
# March-01 March-15 April-01 April-15   May-01   May-15  June-01  June-15 
#      2.0      3.0      1.0      0.0      6.0      0.0      4.0      0.5
```

Another option:

```r
dat$Date <- with(dat, format(as.Date(paste(YEAR, MO, DAY, sep="-")), format = "%B-%d"))
dat
#    STN      NAME MO DAY YEAR SNWD     Date
# 1 1234 STATION A  3   1 1919  2.0 March-01
# 2 1234 STATION A  3  15 1919  3.0 March-15
# 3 1234 STATION A  4   1 1919  1.0 April-01
# 4 1234 STATION A  4  15 1919  0.0 April-15
# 5 1234 STATION A  5   1 1919  6.0   May-01
# 6 1234 STATION A  5  15 1919  0.0   May-15
# 7 1234 STATION A  6   1 1919  4.0  June-01
# 8 1234 STATION A  6  15 1919  0.5  June-15
t(dat[,c("Date", "SNWD")])
#      [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]     [,6]     [,7]      [,8]     
# Date "March-01" "March-15" "April-01" "April-15" "May-01" "May-15" "June-01" "June-15"
# SNWD "2.0"      "3.0"      "1.0"      "0.0"      "6.0"    "0.0"    "4.0"     "0.5"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help r2evans!

Answer (score 0):

With `tidyverse` you can use a very simple pipeline:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- read_csv(...)    # here insert your CSV file

# 1. make a nice date as YEAR-MO-DAY
# 2. select only a DATE and SNWD columns
# 3. make a wide tibble
data %>%
    mutate(DATE = format(as.Date(paste(YEAR, MO, DAY, sep="-")), format = "%B-%d")) %>%
    select(DATE, SNWD) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = DATE, values_from = SNWD)
```

Note that dates are only column names:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 8
    `March-01` `March-15` `April-01` `April-15`   `May-01`   `May-15`  `June-01`  `June-15`
        <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1           2           3          1          0          6          0          4        0.5
```

Comment: Thank you Petr. This question is for anyone. I need to write out the table as a .csv file to my local computer to check the data. What would be the data frame? write.csv(Your DataFrame,"Path where you'd like to export the DataFrame\\File Name.csv", row.names = FALSE).

Comment: @Kris You just assign it to a variable like `new_data <- data %>% mutate...` etc and then you save it as `write_csv(new_data, "file.csv")`.